# How to pass environment variables from docker-compose into the NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a NodeJS application, which I want to docker-size.

The application consists of two parts:

- server part, running an API which is taking data from a DB. This is running on the port 3000;
- client part, which is doing a calls to the API end-points from the server part. This is running on the port 8080;

With this, I have a variable named "server_address" in my client part and it has the value of "localhost:3000". But here is the thing, the both projects should be docker-sized in a separate `Dockerimage` files and combined in one `docker-compose.yml` file.

So due some reasons, I have to run the docker containers via `docker-compose.yml` file. So is it possible to connect these things somehow and to pass the server address externally from dockerfile into the NodeJS project?

**docker-composer.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  client-side-app:
    image: my-client-side-docker-image
    environment:
      - BACKEND_SERVER="here we need to enter backend server"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  server-side-app:
    image: my-server-side-docker-image
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

both of the **Dockerfile**'s looks like:

```
FROM node:8.11.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

by having these files, I have the concern:

- will I be able to use the variable `BACKEND_SERVER` somehow in the project? And if yes, how to do this? I'm not referring to the `Dockerimage` file, instead into the project itself?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: That'll work. But as you're in compose world, you could use the `service` name as the reference (if I'm understanding correctly)

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar so how I will be able to call it? Not sure what are you referring to.

Comment: @RobertMoskal how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Sorry i was reading this on the bus yesterday - If I understand correctly, you can just use the service name `server-side-app` in your client-side config, as `docker-compose` will create a network where those containers can be looked up by their service name - equally the solution by @t-prisar works well!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use process.env in node.js code, like this

```
process.env.BACKEND_SERVER
```

Mention your variable in docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  client-side-app:
    image: my-client-side-docker-image
    environment:
      - BACKEND_SERVER="here we need to enter backend server"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  server-side-app:
    image: my-server-side-docker-image
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, you can alternatively define variables and their values when running a container:

```
docker run --env variable1=value1 --env variable2=value2 <image>
```

Other two different ways are: (1) referring environment variables which you’ve already exported to your local environment and (2) loading the variables from a file:

(1)

```
# In your ~/.bash (or ~/.zshrc) file: export VAR1=value1
docker run --env VAR1 <image>
```

(2)

```
cat env.list
# Add the following in the env.list
# variable1=value1
# variable2=value2
# variable3=value3
docker run --env-file env.list <image>
```

Those options are useful in case you don't want to mention your variables in the docker-compose file.

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just docker without docker-compose, try using the [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) property in the `Dockerfile` to initialise the `process.env.variable`.

If you want to get the env from the CLI or during build time externally, combine it along with [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) property.

Eg `Dockerfile` for reference,

```
FROM node:20-alpine
// here 8000 is the default value if no value is passed during runtime. 
ARG PORT_ARG=8000
ENV PORT=$PORT_ARG
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js" ]
```

Usage in CLI

```
// process.env.PORT will have 8081 as the value because of this step
docker build . --build-arg PORT_ARG=8081  -t web_api

docker run -it web_api
```