# cURL and shell task

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gulp

I am using gulpfile.js in my project to download files and it is working fine.

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
gulp.task('folder_xyz', shell.task('curl --output xyz.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: theyuuin_io2_kj" "https://example.com/api/v4/download?job=xyz"'));
```

here everything is working fine and i am able to download the file. However i have set environment variable in  GitLab called `download_folder_xyz` . Now i  want to use this environment, want to replace Private token with  new variable `download_folder_xyz` in the `gulp.task()` how can i do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass environment variables from docker-compose into the NodeJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650775/how-to-pass-environment-variables-from-docker-compose-into-the-nodejs-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any environment variable in nodejs via process.env object.
Let's see an example.
Assuming you want to access download_folder_xyz that is a environment variable

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
gulp.task('folder_xyz', shell.task(`curl --output xyz.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${process.env.download_folder_xyz}" "https://example.com/api/v4/download?job=xyz"`));
```

Comment: Ok i uploaded the answer

Comment: the code is wrong. The code still uses PRIVATE-TOKEN: 
 theyuuin_io2_kj

Comment: Sorry i miss understood your question.I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

If `download_folder_xyz` has successfully been set as an environment variable, you can retrieve it from `process.env`. The `env` property of the `process` core module hosts all environment variables at the time the process has been started. See the [docs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs) for more information on this.

You can use the enviornment variable just as any other variable and interpolate in the task string. To replace the private token, this is the updated code:

```js
const { download_folder_xyz } = process.env;

var shell = require('gulp-shell');
gulp.task('folder_xyz', shell.task(`curl --output xyz.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${download_folder_xyz}" "https://example.com/api/v4/download?job=xyz"`));
```